# T-SQL Merge from multiple source records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I've seen several similar questions but haven't found one that answers my question.

I have a source table with many individual notes for a company

```
CompanyName, Notes3
Company1, "spoke with someone"
Company2, "Email no longer works"
Company1, "Moved address"
```

I have a destination table (vchCompanyName is unique here)

```
vchCompanyName, vchNotes
Company1, "started business in 2005"
Company2, null
```

I want to end up with

```
vchCompanyName, vchNotes
Company1, "started business in 2005
           spoke with someone
           Moved address"
Company2, "Email no longer works"
```

I have tried this code

```
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName, Notes3 ORDER BY CompanyName) RowNum, *
    FROM CompanyContact
    )

    merge dCompany as target
    using CTE as source
    on target.vchcompanyname = source.companyname 
    when matched and len(source.notes3)>0 and source.RowNum = 1
    then
        update set target.vchnote = vchnote + CHAR(13) + source.Notes3
```

But get the error

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.
>   Which is accurate.

I have also tried `STRING_AGG` but get an undefined UDF error.

How do I change my code to run iteratively?

--EDIT--
I had tried the following update code

```
    WITH CTE
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName, Notes3 ORDER BY CompanyName) RowNum, *
    FROM CompanyContact
    )
    UPDATE dCompany SET vchNote = vchNote + 
    (select CHAR(13) + cc.Notes3 from CompanyContact cc 
    inner JOIN dCompany dc ON dc.vchCompanyName COLLATE database_default = LEFT(cc.CompanyName,50) COLLATE database_default
    inner join CTE on dc.vchCompanyName COLLATE database_default = LEFT(CTE.CompanyName,50) COLLATE database_default
     WHERE LEN(cc.Notes3)>0
     and RowNum = 1     
     );
```

But get the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Why use `MERGE` when the only operation is an `UPDATE`? Why not update the target directly?

Comment: There does not appear to be a column in `<first unnamed table>` that provides an order.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to update the second table with  *concatenated* strings from the first table. That's not a simple UPDATE and definitely doesn't need a MERGE. `STRING_AGG` was added in SQL Server 2017. If you can't use it it means you are using an older version of SQL Server. You'll have to create a custom solution for concatenating strings. [This article by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) explains various techniques and their performance

Comment: Looks like you tried to perform a `quirky update` using `MERGE` instead of `UPDATE`. `MERGE` doesn't allow multiple modifications of the same row. If it did, you'd end up updating the same row you added in the same MERGE statement

Comment: UPDATE *may* work but there's nothing specifying the order of lines. `ROW_NUBMER()` will return a random order and so will *any* string concatenation technique. Table rows have no order unless you specify it with an `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: I had tried merge - added to main question. The order in the source isn't important for my scenario but if it is for the syntax to work then `Notes3 ASC` will suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chris Crawshaw, I will approach this by doing a 'union all' on the source and destination table to pick up all the notes for each company. Then using the STUFF function, it is easy to concatenate all the notes into one cell, while grouping by the induvidual company names. See the mockup below:

```
DECLARE @Source TABLE (CompanyName VARCHAR(20), Notes3 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Source
SELECT 'Company1', 'spoke with someone' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company2', 'Email no longer works' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company1', 'Moved address'

DECLARE @Destination TABLE (vchCompanyName VARCHAR(20), vchNotes VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @Destination
SELECT 'Company1', 'started business in 2005' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company2', NULL




    ;WITH Temp AS (

    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            @Destination D
        WHERE D.vchNotes is not null
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * 
        FROM
            @Source S  

    )h


    )

    update  D
    SET D.vchNotes=U.vchNotes

    FROM @Destination D
    LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT t2.vchCompanyName, vchNotes=STUFF((
        SELECT  ',' + vchNotes
        FROM Temp t1 where t1.vchCompanyName=t2.vchCompanyName
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    FROM
        @Destination t2
    GROUP BY
        t2.vchCompanyName
        )U ON
            U.vchCompanyName=D.vchCompanyName


    --TEST--
            SELECT * 
            FROM
            @Destination
```

Comment: Thanks, that works as a select but I'm struggling to turn it in to an update based on the returned `vchCompanyName`. Also, why is there a h after the close bracket?